# warpPerspective overlapping one image over another on the background

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

So I want to stich two images in panorama style. So here is what I planned:

1. Create a white image (ie : color = 255, 255, 255) that is twice as wide as image1
2. Copy img1 to the (top-)left of this result image, which means an identity transform in terms of pixel coordinates
3. Copy img2 to the result image, by warping it with the inverse of the estimated homography (which maps dst_pts to src_pts)

However, the final result not only set the background to black, but also overlapped second image over first. What am I doing wrong?

The code is below

```
def panorama(img1, img2, H, size):
   I = np.linalg.inv(H)
   img = np.zeros(size,dtype=np.uint8)
   img.fill(255)
   img = cv2.warpPerspective(img1, np.identity(3), size, img, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_TRANSPARENT)
   img = cv2.warpPerspective(img2, I, size, img, flags=cv2.WARP_INVERSE_MAP+cv2.INTER_LINEAR, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_TRANSPARENT)
   return img

size = (2 * image1.shape[0],image1.shape[1])
cv2.imshow([panorama(image1, image2, H, size)],["Panorama"])
```

Comment: Warp to a third image and copy all non-black pixels to your target image. There is no blending included in the warping, so you need that extra step.

Comment: What is the `H` in the last line ? It could be better to share the results to see what the wrong is

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk ```H``` is the homography matrix. It's a numpy.ndarray since it's being passed to numpy.linalg.inv.

Comment: Also @AndeleTodorovic this code gives rise to an error in the Python3 opencv API. The following correctly displays the image along with the intended label:       ```cv2.imshow("Panorama", panorama(image1, image2, H, size))```

Answer (score 0):

I actually resolved it by using original homography (H) instead of the inverse (I) in warpPerspective